# interior product definition for $k>1$ $k$-vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, exterior-algebra

On wikipedia exterior algebra page, section Hodge duality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Hodge_duality) I read the following definition:

....Then the interior product induces a canonical isomorphism of vector spaces

$
{\textstyle\bigwedge}^k(V^*) \otimes {\textstyle\bigwedge}^n(V)
\to {\textstyle\bigwedge}^{n-k}(V)
$

by the recursive definition

$ i_{\alpha \wedge \beta} = i_\beta \circ i_\alpha. $

I find the formula natural, but I haven't been able to check it. Furthermore I have not seen anything in the "classical" litterature, where interior product is taken only on a 1-vector.

Can anyone confirm, or tell some references?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in Werner Greub's *Multilinear Algebra*, 1st Edition (but **not** the 2nd Edition).

In short the 1-form interior product you're familar with gives a map $V^* \to \mathrm{End}(\bigwedge V)$ and the universal property of $\bigwedge V^*$ extends it to a homomorphism $\bigwedge V^* \to \mathrm{End}(\bigwedge V)$ (or antihomomorphism in your case, using the opposite algebra of endomorphisms instead).

The isomorphism they reference is called the Poincaré isomorphism and you can find it in Greub also. We choose any nonzero $I \in \bigwedge^nV$ and get (one of) the Poincaré isomorphism(s) $\bigwedge V^* \to \bigwedge V$ via
$$
  \omega \mapsto i_\omega(I).
$$
Another way to construct these isomorphisms is to identify $\bigwedge V^*$ with $(\bigwedge V)^*$ and then note that the bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle : \bigwedge V\times\bigwedge V \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$
  \langle A\wedge B\rangle_n = \langle A,B\rangle I
$$
is nondegenerate, where $\langle\cdot\rangle_n$ is the projection onto grade $n$. (We might need to throw in a reversal to get the signs to match up with your convention.) Then $X \mapsto \langle{X,\cdot}\rangle$ is (one of) the Poincaré isomorphism(s) associated with $I$.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas for your anszer, and the reference of W.Breug's book. I need to dig some more, into it.

Comment: (...) Looking at the Poincaré isomorphism (page 149, first edition) although it seems natural to me, if the $e_{\nu_{i}}$ and $e^{*\nu_{i}}$ are dual bases, does that necessarily mean that the $e_{\nu_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge e_{\nu_{k}}$  and $e^{*\nu_{1}} \wedge \dots \wedge  e^{*\nu_{k}}$ are dual as well? This seems a bit fast to me.  I need to work on it.

Comment: @LPSfr No, it can't because the isomorphism in grade-reversing (just like the closely related Hodge star): a $k$-vector is mapped to an $(n-k)$-covector.

Comment: However, the Poincare isomorphism is "geometry preserving" in the following sense: We can think of vectors as representing lines, whence we can think of their wedge products as "the spaces built up from lines" with the wedge product of two simple multivectors being the simple multivector representing their span. We can think of covectors as hyperplanes, whence we can think of their wedge products as "the spaces built down from hyperplanes" using intersections.

Comment: Now, the dual $e^{*i}$ of $e_i$ represents the hyperplane spanned by $e_2,\dotsc,e_k$, which is what $e_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_k$ represents, and indeed applying the Poincare isomorphism to this $(k-1)$-vector will yield $\pm e^{*1}$.